# How does db:seed act on existing seed data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
rake db:seed
```

Does rerunning seed data drop the existing seed data and re-create or adds just the new records whenever you modify the seed data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `rake db:seed`, db/seeds.rb is only included with the rails environment.
Therefore, nothing else is done on your database than what you mention it to do.

I usually put the following at the top of my db/seeds file :

```
Dir['app/models/**/*.rb'].each do |model|
    model_object = model.camelize.constantize
    model_object.delete_all
end
```

This way, all previous seed data is removed, and I get this fresh new proper data I want in my dev environment.

Comment: If I have been using some seed data, I would prefer not to touch them since I could have created some test data which has references to the seed data. So I would prefer just to add the delta seed data once it has been provisioned before.

Comment: rake db:reset drops the db, creates it, loads the schema, then adds the seeds.